# Showing that DP is a subset of EXPTIME

Tags: complexity-theory

The complexity class $\mathit{DP}$ is defined as follows: $L \in \mathit{DP}$ if $L = L_1 \cap L_2$ where $L_1 \in \mathit{NP}$ and $L_2 \in \mathit{coNP}$.

I'm trying to show that $\mathit{DP} \subseteq \mathit{EXPTIME}$.

My idea was as follows:

For all $L \in \mathit{DP}$, $L = L_1 \cap L_2$, where $L_1 \in \mathit{NP}$ and $L_2 \in \mathit{coNP}$.

Therefore, for all $x \in L$, $x \in L_1 \cap L_2$ implies that $x \in L_1$.

Determining whether $x \in L \in \mathit{DP}$ is equivalent to determining whether $x \in L_1 \in \mathit{NP}$.

As $\mathit{NP} \subseteq \mathit{EXPTIME}$, $\mathit{DP} \subseteq \mathit{EXPTIME}$.

I'm not sure if my argument is correct, especially the part where I reduce determining whether $x \in L$ to determining whether $x \in L_1$, as it might not be known which two languages intersected to form $L$.

Is this proof wrong? If so, how do I prove that $\mathit{DP} \subseteq \mathit{EXPTIME}$?

Comment: According to your definition of DP, it is equal to NP∩coNP.

Comment: You seem to be assuming a different definition of DP, namely a language is in DP if it is the intersection of a language in NP and a language in coNP. This means that if a language is in DP, then it is of the form $L_1 \cap L_2$, where $L_1$ is in NP and $L_2$ is in coNP. The assumption that the language is in DP implies the existence of $L_1,L_2$, *by definition*. You don't need to "find them", like you seem to assume.

Comment: On the other hand, while it is true that $x \in L_1 \cap L_2$ implies $x \in L_1$, the reverse implication doesn't hold in general (unless $L_1 \subseteq L_2$). Using your line of reasoning, you can show that the halting problem is in EXPTIME: take $L_1$ to consist of all strings, which is trivially in NP, and let $L_2$ be the halting problem.

Comment: Yep sorry, I'd mistyped the definition of DP, I've edited the post. I see where my proof went wrong. Any ideas on how to prove that it's a subset of $EXPTIME$ then?

Comment: I suggest spending more time on it.

Comment: $DP \subseteq P^{NP} \subseteq PH \subseteq PSPACE \subseteq EXPTIME$